# Regex causing console.log to be empty

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to filter a json using regex, so that from the below just the digits from the "date" field remain. If I remove the regex from the manderleySurveyGet function then I receive the below in my terminal due to the console.log in Landing.js. However if the regex is left in I get nothing in my terminal. I tested the regex in regex101 and according to that it *should* work.

Terminal

```
   SURVEY API RESULT LANDING: Array [
  Object {
    "_id": "6162204f1a03eed562de2e60",
    "date": "10 10 2021",
    "formResponse": "Survey completed",
    "timeStamp": "12:05",
    "userId": "email@gmail.com",
  },
]
```

Landing.js:

```
manderleySurveyGet()
.then(response => {
      console.log("SURVEY API RESULT LANDING:", response);
})
.catch(err => {
      err.message;
});
```

api.js:

```
export async function manderleySurveyGet () {
    let response = await axios.get('http://localhost:6000/');

    return response.data.replace(/[\d]{1,2} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}/gm);
}
```

surveyApi.js:

```
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("manderleydb");
        var query = { userId : /^(.)/ };
        dbo.collection("manderleySurveyCompleted").find(query).sort({ date: 1}).limit(1)
            .toArray(function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(result);
                db.close();
                res.status(200).send(result);
        });
    });
});

app.listen(6000, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 6000');
});
```

Comment: `.replace` requires 2 parameters, no? You gave 1

Comment: do a `console.log(response)` to see the content to replace

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), `replace` should take at least two arguments, otherwise  you'll be in trouble. In your case, you wanted:

> replace(regexp, newSubstr)

But you wrote:  `replace(regexp)`. So, you got just the opposite:

> If newSubstr is an empty string, then the substring given by substr, or the matches for regexp, are **removed** (rather then being replaced).

If you want to extract the date, the solution is to use the proper method `match` instead of `replace`, making sure it is a String.

```js
var response = {
  data:{
    "_id": "6162204f1a03eed562de2e60",
    "date": "10 10 2021",
    "formResponse": "Survey completed",
    "timeStamp": "12:05",
    "userId": "email@gmail.com",
  }
}
  
var date = JSON.stringify(response.data).match(/[\d]{2} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}/gm)
console.log(date)
```

Comment: I've updated my .replace to return response.data.replace(/[\d]{1,2} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}/gm, ''); and unfortunately my terminal is still returning nothing

Comment: Try to `JSON.stringify(response.data)` because it returns an object and you can use replace in Strings only